# form submit button returns null if value contains non-latin words

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

this is my HTML:

```
    <?php echo form_open(base_url().'admin'); ?>
        <div class="row username">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <input type="text" value="" name="username" placeholder="Όνομα" />
        </div>
        <div class="row password">
            <span class="icon"></span>
            <input type="password" value="" name="password" placeholder="Κωδικος Πρόσβασης" />
        </div>
        <div class="row button">
            <input type="submit" value="Σύνδεση" name="submit" />
        </div>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

so the button has as value "Σύνδεση" and when i click the submit button it returns nothing(null string)...

if i replace it with a text like "Sign in" it will work...

why it wont allow me to use non-latin characters?

Comment: What charset is your page using? You have to ensure that the SAME character set is used throughout the entire HTTP and PHP pipeline.

Comment: @MarcB <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was my MAMP version was old, something was wrong or so... so i removed it and added XAMPP for Mac OSX and its fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you posting everything on the same page? If you are making it post on a different page, make sure you have the same content type there too.

Comment: on the same page... content type is the same

Comment: @fxuser does it submit the other values or none at all?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your php file is encoded in utf-8. You can check it with a text-editor program like EditPad. Then you may consider using form attribute `accept-charset` and set it to UTF-8. Make sure your page meta is utf-8 as well. Finally check codeigniter application config.php and make sure `$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8'`. Hope this helps.

Plus, make sure you have no `validation rules` which prevents input other than basic latin like `alpha-dash`

Plus regarding php file encoding, try to make sure `BOM` is not set.